# Android Development: setImageResource Causing Force Close?

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, drawable

I have a basic file browser within my app that for each row of the list, outputs an ImageView and a TextView.

A few lines into my code I do a isDirectory() (located below somewhere) on the current file/folder that is being added to the ListView, so that I can set a folder image as the icon for that row if it is a folder, or set a file image as the icon if it's a file.

But when I run the file browser activity, it force closes.

I checked DDMS and it tells me it's a NullPointerException on the following line of code:

```
listicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.foldericon);
```

Which is located in the following statement:

```
if(file.isDirectory()){
listicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.foldericon);
}else{
listicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.fileicon);
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong? Eclipse isn't giving me any errors for that line, and foldericon and fileicon do exist in my drawable folder.

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());  
     View newView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.the_layout, null);
and then: listicon = (ImageView) newView.findViewById(R.id.listiconXML);

Answer (score 0):

Your `listicon` variable is null. Did you properly initialize it? Maybe `findViewById` couldn't find the resource in your current activity's layout.

Comment: yeah just above the if statement ImageView listicon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.listicon); I haven't done a setContentView(), maybe that's why?

Comment: Yes, that could be it. If that's not it, then maybe the `listicon` view is in the layout xml for another activity.

Comment: But if I try setContentView with anything it causes a force close too :(

Comment: Yep. I don't get this, setting the image resource manually in the xml file works fine but doing it at runtime is a fail :(.

Comment: Setting the image resource isn't the problem; the `listicon` view has to be found first. In order to be able to find it, you need to call setContentView, or else it won't work. Maybe you simply made a typo somewhere.

Comment: I see now, I'll try setting the view I planned to after checking it for typos, then if that doesn't work I'm going to cry!

Comment: You need to show us your stacktrace for your crash. We can't just guess why it crashes